# Search result updating on crawl

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I have used search query web part to show all the subsites in a site. But sometimes I am facing the issue that, it does not show the new site created or also few sites that were deleted, it shows up in a search result web part. But when I click on that deleted site, it shows that the `Page not found`.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/sharepoint-online-search-results-still-showing/d636a004-20b8-4d5a-97e9-9b7bb45af70b

Comment: I have deleted it from recycle bin and also indexed but still those deleted site appear in result.